# powershell cannot bind error on if else block

Tags: powershell

I am working on a requirement where I have to check if the api call needs to be looped over or not. I am using the below code to accomplish this requirement. If I take out the if else block and write for either loop no loop things work as expected.

***PoSh:***

```
    $Loop = "1" # 0 for no looping 1 for looping
    
    if ($Loop -eq 1) {
    
    $Header = @{
        "authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    }
    #make REST API call
    $Parameters = @{
        Method      = "GET"
        Headers     = $Header
        ContentType = "application/json"
        Body        = $BodyJson
    }
    $startYear = 2014
    $endYear = 2022
    
    $Data = {for($year=$startYear; $i -le $endYear; $year=$year+1) {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.mysite.com/v1/data/year/Year/" + [string]$year @Parameters -DisableKeepAlive -ErrorAction Stop}} | ConvertTo-Json
    
    }
    
    else {Write-Output "No loop"
    $Header = @{
        "authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    }
    #make REST API call
    $Parameters = @{
        Method      = "GET"
        Headers     = $Header
        ContentType = "application/json"
        Body        = $BodyJson
    }
    
    $Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.mysite.com/v1/data" @Parameters -DisableKeepAlive -ErrorAction Stop | ConvertTo-Json

}
```

***Error:***

```
Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Uri' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax.
```

Comment: `"https://api.mysite.com/v1/data" + [string]$year` should be `("https://api.mysite.com/v1/data" + [string]$year)`. While in a scriptblock, the commands won't execute either, not sure if that's your intentions. You `ConvertTo-Json` is outside your `else` statement as well.

Comment: That was a typo in the OP. I modified it.

Comment: same goes for the `$data` in your `if` statement. The error should narrow down the line that's giving you that exception. Guessing it's the one in your `for` loop but, not sure if that's a typo as well

Comment: For some reason they work fine when independently but when I put it together in the if else block that's when it runs into error.

Comment: More typo's... You define a Hashtable for splatting in variable `$Parameters`, but on the Invoke-RestMethod you use `@params`. The for loop is wrong too, You define a looping variable `$year`, but then you use `$i -le $endYear`, so an undefined variable `$i` instead of `$year`. Also, since for both cases the `$Header` and `$Parameters` Hashtable are the same, why not define that only once above the if..else construct? and lastly, why not simply use `-Uri "https://api.mysite.com/v1/data/year/Year/$year"` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have of course no idea what your `https://api.mysite.com/v1/data` would return and if it is actually needed to convert the returned data to Json at all, but continuing from my comments, try

```
# make this a Boolean value for clarity
$Loop = $true   # $false for no looping $true for looping


# splatting Hashtable for REST API call
$Parameters = @{
    Method           = "GET"
    Headers          = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $token" }
    ContentType      = "application/json"
    Body             = $BodyJson
    # you can incorporate these parameters as well
    DisableKeepAlive = $true
    ErrorAction      = 'Stop'
}

if ($Loop) {
    Write-Host "Start looping.."
    $startYear = 2014
    $endYear   = 2022
    # use the $() subexpression to combine the various outputs and convert that to Json
    $Data = $(for ($year = $startYear; $year -le $endYear; $year++) {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.mysite.com/v1/data/year/Year/$year" @Parameters
    }) | ConvertTo-Json
}
else {
    Write-Host "No loop"
    $Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.mysite.com/v1/data" @Parameters | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

<sup>P.S. The error you saw in your code was caused by the wrong variable you used in the `for` loop with `$i -le $endYear` instead of `$year -le $endYear`. That and the fact that you put the whole loop inside a scriptblock made variables `$startYear` and `$endYear` invisible..</sup>